# How do I avoid instances intersecting each other?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, intersection

I have a curve to mesh object (stem) that has instances scattered along the surface randomly (thorns). They are perpendicular to the mesh normals and they rotated randomly.

I would like to achieve:

**That the instances do not intersect each other or the base object (see picture)**
[image]
How can I achieve this? Raycast node? Geometry proximity node?